# Select all classes after the first of its type

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

If I have the following HTML structure

```
<section class="main-gallery homeowner-rating content-block">
  <!--content-->
</section>

<section class="homeowner-rating content-block">
  <!--content-->
</section>

<section class="homeowner-rating content-block">
  <!--content-->
</section>

<section class="homeowner-rating content-block">
  <!--content-->
</section>
```

How do I select all the `homeowner-rating.content-block` classes except the first one?

To give some context I have setup a simple screen-scrape using Nokogiri but it is trying to grab information from the first section class which returns a blank result.

```
def get_testimonials
  url = 'http://www.ratedpeople.com/profile/lcc-building-and-construction'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open url)
  testimonial_section = doc.css('.homeowner-rating.content-block').each do |t|
    title = t.css('h4').text.strip
    comments = t.css('q').text.strip
    author = t.css('cite').text.strip
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current setup, there are multiple ways:

```
.homeowner-rating+.homeowner-rating
{
   color: red;  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKEv5/

```
.homeowner-rating:not(.main-gallery)
{
   color: red;  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKEv5/1/

This will only work if the main gallery is the first-child of a node:

```
.homeowner-rating:not(:first-child)
{
   color: red;  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKEv5/2/

Comment: thanks very much, can i pass two options, so not(.main-gallery) and not(:last-child) ?

Comment: absolutely, `.homeowner-rating:not(.main-gallery):not(:last-child)` http://jsfiddle.net/PKEv5/3/

Comment: ah yes you can, i can just chain them

Answer (score 1):

Using Nokogiri it's easy:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<section class="main-gallery homeowner-rating content-block">
  <p>1</p>
</section>

<section class="homeowner-rating content-block">
  <p>2</p>
</section>

<section class="homeowner-rating content-block">
  <p>3</p>
</section>

<section class="homeowner-rating content-block">
  <p>4</p>
</section>
EOT

doc.css('.homeowner-rating')[1..-1].map(&:to_html)
# => ["<section class=\"homeowner-rating content-block\">\n  <p>2</p>\n</section>",
#     "<section class=\"homeowner-rating content-block\">\n  <p>3</p>\n</section>",
#     "<section class=\"homeowner-rating content-block\">\n  <p>4</p>\n</section>"]
```

Nokogiri's `search`, `css` and `xpath` methods return NodeSets, which behave like an Array, so you can slice the result to grab chunks.